# How can I import code to a Activex Control Button on another page?

Tags: vba, excel

I have use a button (by clicking) to create a new sheet and insert a button on it, but I want to import codes to the new button (here is MyPrecodedButton).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim z As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet, wsnew As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

z = ws2.Cells(2, 1).Value

Set wsnew = Sheets.Add ' Declare your New Sheet in order to be able to work with after
wsnew.Name = "PIAF_Summary" & z

z = z + 1

With wsnew.Range("A1:G1")
        .Merge
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 23
        .Value = "Project Name (To be reviewed by WMO)"
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 13
 End With
ws2.Cells(2, 1).Value = z

Dim Rngc As Range: Set Rngc = wsnew.Range("F35")
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Rngc.Left, Top:=Rngc.Top, Width:=205, Height:=20)
    .Name = "MyPrecodedButton" ' change the name
End With
End sub
```

Here is the code for MyPrecodedButton

```
Public Sub MyPrecodedButton_Click()
    MsgBox "Co-Cooo!"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have thought well, you don't have to inject codes (make your code work with any situation).

Comment: the easy way is by creating a template sheet add all controls you need with code and format it as you need (merge,color...etc.) and hide this sheet and every time you need to add new sheet just copy the template sheet and give it a new name and unhide it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's demonstrate briefly what you can do with VBA to Add buttons.

Below code will Add a button to cell B2 if the ActiveSheet is not "Sheet1".

```
Option Explicit

Sub SayHello()
    MsgBox "Hello from """ & ActiveSheet.Name & """"
End Sub

Sub AddButton()
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim oBtns As Buttons ' Add "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" to References if you want intellisense
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then ' Only works if it's not "Sheet1"
        Set oRng = Range("B2")
        Set oBtns = ActiveSheet.Buttons
        With oBtns.Add(oRng.Left * 1.05, oRng.Top * 1.05, oRng.Width * 0.9, oRng.Height * 2 * 0.9)
            .Caption = "Say Hello!"
            .OnAction = "SayHello"
        End With
        Set oBtns = Nothing
        Set oRng = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Before and After screenshots:
[image: Before]   [image: After]

Now Clicking on the button:
[image: Action]

So, if you code is generic enough (to work with all your possible situations), there is no need to Add Codes via code. i.e. have your codes ready, then just assign the button's `OnAction` property to call the correct `Sub`.